# diving into the Linux Kernel TTY serial source code

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port

Good day all!

Diving into the kernel 5.14 source to solve a problem using a serial port.

Does anyone have the time to help me get a 10,000 feet overview?

Which source files do I care about among the hundreds in drivers/tty and driver/tty/serial?

I have a good book on the subject which describes the tty core driver and the three types of sub drivers.

I need to see the driver responsible for raw mode (no line discipline).

I want to start at the top and see all the way down to hardware code.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Which source files do I care about among the hundreds in drivers/tty and driver/serial?"* -- Obviously the relevant code would be in the ***core*** tty (and perhaps serial) code, rather than any hardware specific code.  Obvious places to start looking are where/how ICANON flag/mode is processed and where/how the line discipline is called (or not called).  *"I need to see the driver responsible for raw mode ... and see all the way down to hardware code"* -- You're confused.  E.G. the received serial data is treated as binary bytes until the upper-layer terminal subsystem gets it.

Comment: *"Diving into the kernel 5.14 source to solve a problem using a serial port.

Does anyone have the time to help me get a 10,000 feet overview?"* -- An odd variation of the XY problem.

Comment: Everything I would care about seems to be under /drivers/tty/.         I see that tty_io.c and tty_ioctl.c are the tty_core I see mentioned in my books?      Under /drivers/tty/serial/ there is a serial_core.c as well.          Also see several other tty_*.c.         Book says there are three driver types under tty:       console, pty, and serial.   I care only about serial.   Which file would that be?

Comment: I see /drivers/tty/serial/8250/ ... filed with 8250 files.    Is this where the most popular UART HAL code lives?     I have a new 16C950 four port card and if I am right the 16xxx are zupped up 8250?

Comment: Great resource: https://bootlin.com/doc/legacy/serial-drivers/linux-serial-drivers.pdf

Comment: You seem to be paralyzed by planning (in)decision.  Following one of my own suggestions, a search for `icanon` in the **drivers/** subdirectory reported just two (2) files!  Lines that contained `icanon` also had interesting variable names such as `raw` and `real_raw`.

Comment: thanks sawdust ... very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one who frequents this forum seems to know ... I will start an answer. I will add/edit as I go thru the source code and also read the 7 books I have purchased on this subject. Please let me know if I have anything incorrect.

---

**There are three classes of tty drivers:**

1. console
2. pty
3. serial

I will focus only on the non USB serial (i.e. ttySx) ... and the most common PC based 8250 UART variant (there are other options).

---

The relevant kernel headers are:

1. drivers/tty/tty.h
2. include/linux/serial.h
3. include/linux/serial_core.h
4. include/uapi/linux/serial.h
5. include/uapi/linux/serial_core.h
6. drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250.h

---

**The TTY Core (top layer):**

drivers/tty/tty_io.c

---

**The line discipline (upper mid layer):**

... which is optional (and there are 17 of these)

The default is:

drivers/tty/n_tty.c

---

**The serial core (lower mid layer)**

(The serial core simplifies lower level UART driver development)

1. drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c

**The UART driver (lowest layer):**

... since my case is a PC with PCI bus visible 8250 / 16550 ...

1. drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_core.c
2. drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_pci.c
3. drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_port.c
4. drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_dma.c

From ... Documentation/driver-api/serial/driver.rst ...

"The uart_ops structure is the main interface between serial_core and the
hardware specific driver."

... for more info ... see Documentation/driver-api/serial/driver.rst.